# ES6: Re-defining exported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Given a 3rd party library that exports a function and uses this function in its internal logic - is there any way to re-define this function? 
For example:

**third-party.js**

```
export function a() {
 console.log('a');
}

export function b() {
 a();
}
```

**my-module.js**

```
import * as tp from 'third-party';

//Re-define, something like this
Object.defineProperty(tp, 'a', { writable: true, value: () => console.log('c')});

//Call b and get the re-define function called
tp.b(); //Expected output: 'c'
```

A few highlights:

- I don't need it for testing, but for production (yes, I know it would be a dirty hack)
- Yes, I'm aware of imports being [live read-only views](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values), I'm looking for a workaround to overcome this constraint
- No, I can't change the code of the 3rd party library
- I need my change to actually change the logic of the 3rd party. I'd like to *call a function that calls* `a` and not `a` itself.

Comment: No, it's impossible to do without patching the code (which might be possible to by script), if the `a()` call reference is to a local `a` variable.

Comment: What environment is this executed in? Are you using a custom loader, a bundler or something?

Comment: Nope, it's pure node environment. I have a certain degree of flexibility for my script though. Meaning I could bundle it (which I'm not doing now).

Comment: You can try experimenting with https://github.com/elastic/require-in-the-middle

Answer (score 2):

Exported module is read-only. So, you can't do such.

```
delete tp.a;
tp.a = () => {
  console.log('c')
}
tp.a() // 'c'
tp.b() // You'll still get 'a'
// it's because, b is calling exported function a
```

If you wish `tp.b()` need the value overridden, then you don't export them but call in an instance. In your example code, just export `a` not `b`. But since, you're trying to override it from the third-party library. It's not possible to do so.

But if you insist using them, then you must override both functions.

```
const obj = {...tp}
obj.a = () => {
  console.log('c')
}

obj.b() // 'a'

obj.b = () => {
  obj.a()
}

obj.b() // 'c'
```

Comment: I did try it, and it didn't work. The issue here is the exports not the assignment to an object. The question specifically asks about exports.

Comment: I made a [small modification](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7xx2j38zy) to conform to the question and it doesn't work. I'd like to call `b` and not `a`. I'm sorry but your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Updated my answer. What you're looking for is not possible.